# Laravel route cache on custom route files

Tags: php, laravel, caching, laravel-5, laravel-routing

I'm building a project in Laravel 5.2 which had a big (big as in a lot of lines) `routes.php`. To make the routes a little cleaner for the eyes, I've split all the route groups intro separated files. In `app\Http\Routes\`.

I require all the files in the `RouteServiceProvider` which works (correction: worked..) perfectly fine for me. After all this I wanted to cache the routes with `php artisan route:cache`. Then if you went to a page all you get is a 404 error.

“Long” story short: New route logic is crashing AFTER artisan route cache.

This is my map function in `RouteServiceProvider` (inspired by [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16574738/2783759) answer):

```
public function map(Router $router)
{
    $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        // Dynamically include all files in the routes directory
        foreach (new \DirectoryIterator(app_path('Http/Routes')) as $file)
        {
            if (!$file->isDot() && !$file->isDir() && $file->getFilename() != '.gitignore')
            {
                require_once app_path('Http/Routes').DS.$file->getFilename();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Does someone know what the problem is? Or do I just need to put everything back in routes.php if I want to use route caching. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Use require instead of require_once and you should be ok.

So, for starters, let's take a look at `Illuminate\Foundation\Console\RouteCacheCommand`.
You'll notice that it uses `getFreshApplicationRoutes` method which bootstraps application and fetches routes from router.

I've used this code to create a command that'll do the routes counting:

```
$app = require $this->laravel->bootstrapPath().'/app.php';

$app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Console\Kernel')->bootstrap();

$routesCnt = $app['router']->getRoutes()->count();

$this->info($routesCnt);
```

This allows us to have more understanding on how many routes are fetched.

With your code, no matter how many files I've added in `Http\Routes` folder, none of them got registered.
So I've decided to try using "require" instead of "require_once".
And voila!

Count of routes increased appropriately.

As to why is this happening, I'm guessing it's because of composer autoloading (this is just an **educated guess**).
Take a look at composer.json:

```
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
```

This means that files in app/ folder are auto-loaded. Which means that these files are already loaded, just not in place that you want them.
Which means that they won't get loaded again if you're using `*_once` inclusion functions.

Code in `RouteServiceProvider.php`, method `map` that worked for me is:

```
$router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router) {
        // Dynamically include all files in the routes directory
        foreach (new \DirectoryIterator(app_path('Http/Routes')) as $file)
        {
            $path = app_path('Http/Routes').DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$file->getFilename();
            if ($file->isDot() || $file->isDir() || $file->getFilename() == '.gitignore')
                continue;

            require $path;
            $included[] = $path;
        }
    });
```